# While C++ gave result different from what I expected

Tags: c++, rcpp

I am new to C++ and currently trying to learn WHILE loop.
But there is a problem I don't understand about my code that gave me a result different from what I expected. Here is it:

```
int i = 1;
double ans = 1.00;
while (ans > 0.1) {
  ans = 1 / i;
  i++;
}
cout << "ans: " << ans;
```

I am expecting to have: ans : 0.1, but is was always giving me: ans : 0.
Can you tell me what I have done wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `1 / i` -> `1. / i`. [Demo](https://ideone.com/GpPzD1).

Comment: The loop is irrelevant. A much smaller demonstration: `cout << 1/10;`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow -- and to Rcpp!  There will be a lot to learn for Rcpp, so take your time. I always found working on examples best, maybe see the [RcppExamples](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppExamples/index.html) package  and the 100+ posts on the [Rcpp Gallery](https://gallery.rcpp.org/) for inspiration.  And do look at the 10+ vignettes, particular the intro one(s) and the FAQ one.  I closed this question as the C/C++ issue of int division has nothing to do with Rcpp per se, and has come up before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decision on whether to do integer or floating point division depends on the type of the operands.

Unless at least one of them is of floating point type, you will have an integer division.

The type of the variable you assign the result to does not matter.

Comment: thank you so much, I have been working on solving this shit for days. Thank you so much